# WPF/Silverlight: Find the name of a color

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Is there a way to get the name of a color. The color is a System.Windows.Media.Color and the names I'm looking for are defined as properties on the System.Windows.Media.Colors module.

Comment: Do you mean by providing RGB values and then getting the named color (if it exists) back?

Answer (score 4):

Try this extension method:

```
static class ColorHelpers
{

    public static string GetColorName(this Color color)
    {
        return _knownColors
            .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Equals(color))
            .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    static readonly Dictionary<string, Color> _knownColors = GetKnownColors();

    static Dictionary<string, Color> GetKnownColors()
    {
        var colorProperties = typeof(Colors).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        return colorProperties
            .ToDictionary(
                p => p.Name,
                p => (Color)p.GetValue(null, null));
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
Color c = ...;
string name = c.GetColorName();
```

*EDIT: this is roughly the same as Meleak's answer, but it should be faster since the reflection is only done once...*

Answer (score 0):

Modified answer from Thomas Levesque to populate the Dictionary only when 1st needed, instead of taking the cost at startup (going to use at speech recognition-driven turtle graphics, so that user can pronounce known color names to change the turtle's pen color)

```
//Project: SpeechTurtle (http://SpeechTurtle.codeplex.com)
//Filename: ColorUtils.cs
//Version: 20150901

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SpeechTurtle.Utils
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Color-related utility methods
  /// </summary>
  public static class ColorUtils //based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475391/wpf-silverlight-find-the-name-of-a-color
  {
    #region --- Fields ---

    private static Dictionary<string, Color> knownColors; //=null

    #endregion

    #region --- Methods ---

    #region Extension methods

    public static string GetKnownColorName(this Color color)
    {
      return GetKnownColors()
          .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Equals(color))
          .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
          .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static Color GetKnownColor(this string name)
    {
      Color color;
      return GetKnownColors().TryGetValue(name, out color) ? color : Colors.Black; //if color for name is not found, return black
    }

    #endregion

    public static Dictionary<string, Color> GetKnownColors()
    {
      if (knownColors == null)
      {
        var colorProperties = typeof(Colors).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        knownColors = colorProperties.ToDictionary(
          p => p.Name,
          p => (Color)p.GetValue(null, null));
      }
      return knownColors;
    }

    public static string[] GetKnownColorNames()
    {
      return GetKnownColors().Keys.ToArray();
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```